# How to filter on this artifact in the HTML?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using this code and it works:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import requests
page = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOGL?p=GOOGL")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
fin-streamer= soup.find("fin-streamer", class_="Fz(36px)")
print(fin-streamer)
print (fin-streamer.get_text())
```

It prints this for fin-streamer:

```
<fin-streamer active="" class="Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-field="regularMarketPrice" data-pricehint="2" data-reactid="47" data-symbol="GOOGL" data-test="qsp-price" data-trend="none" value="2897.04">2,897.04</fin-streamer>
```

What I'd like to do is filter on something more useful than the Fz(36px) class, such as

```
data-symbol="GOOGL"
```

but I don't know the syntax for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary:

```py
fin_streamer = soup.find("fin-streamer", {"data-symbol":"GOOGL"})
```

Answer (score 2):

#### How to select?

To select your element more specific, simply take use of `css selectors`:

```
soup.select_one('fin-streamer[data-symbol="GOOGL"]')
```

Above line selects the first `<fin-streamer>` with attribute `data-symbol="GOOGL"` - To get its value just call `['value]` as alternativ call `.text` method.

**Note:** *There is a difference in format of value / text*

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOGL?p=GOOGL")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup.select_one('fin-streamer[data-symbol="GOOGL"]')['value']
```