# Yahoo finance beautifulsoup artifact parsing

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors, yahoo-finance

The following correct & useful answer was provided to question [How to filter on this artifact in the HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70556917/how-to-filter-on-this-artifact-in-the-html)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests  
page = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOGL?p=GOOGL")  
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')  
soup.select_one('fin-streamer[data-symbol="GOOGL"]')['value']
```

I find the same `fin-streamer[data-symbol="GOOGL"]` on https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOGL/key-statistics but adjusting the code (below) does not work for that page

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOGL/key-statistics")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup.select_one('fin-streamer[data-symbol="GOOGL"]')['value']
```

I get this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3b1c0b9e0480> in <module>
      3 page = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOGL/key-statistics")
      4 soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
----> 5 soup.select_one('fin-streamer[data-symbol="GOOGL"]')['value']

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Could you help me find out why?

The reason for my request is that I am seeking to avoid having to load / parse the quote page that is otherwise not needed or useful compared to the key statistics page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Always and first of all, take a look at your soup to see if all the expected ingredients are in place.*

You have to add a [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) to your request headers to get the right source back from the server:

```
page = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOGL/key-statistics", headers={'user-agent':'some-agent'})
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOGL/key-statistics", headers={'user-agent':'some-agent'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup.select_one('fin-streamer[data-symbol="GOOGL"]')['value']
```

Comment: This works in Jupyter, thank you so much, also for your patience on the other thread.  I am puzzled why one yahoo page does not require the headers, while the other does, for the same set of data!

Comment: Oh there can be many different reasons for that, one in particular would be that `requests` without customisation just doesn't imitate a browser / human user.